# Convert row values to columns in Access SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have two columns in an Access table

```
Idea_Code, "Dependency_Name" 
I66666       TEST1
I66666       TEST2
I66666       TEST3
I77777       TEST34
```

I would like to see the results as:

```
Idea_Code  Dependency_Name1  Dependency_Name2  Dependency_Name3 ------ETC
I66666         TEST1               TEST2          TEST3 
I77777         TEST34
```

One idea code could have many dependency name. In order to kill duplication I need to show dependency names as columns which could be one to many relationships. Thanks for your time on it.

I used this code but it doesn't work the way I would like it to in the access query.

```
TRANSFORM First(DA.dependency_name) AS dependency_name
SELECT DA.idea_code
FROM tbl_IdeasDependencies AS DA

GROUP BY DA.idea_code

PIVOT DA.dependency_name;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server  Try that.

Comment: Thanks Duston, My qry is in Access Database, that solution won't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried developing the query in the SQL View?

Answer (score 2):

First you create a new colum `row_number`, here is a [**SAMPLE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917637/achieving-row-number-partition-by-in-ms-access) how

You will have

```
Idea_Code, "Dependency_Name", row_number
I66666       TEST1                1
I66666       TEST2                2
I66666       TEST3                3
I77777       TEST34               1
```

Second you create a `category` column

```
SELECT 'Dependency_Name' + row_number as category
```

Now you have

```
Idea_Code, "Dependency_Name", row_number, category
I66666       TEST1                1       Dependency_Name1
I66666       TEST2                2       Dependency_Name2        
I66666       TEST3                3       Dependency_Name3
I77777       TEST34               1       Dependency_Name1
```

Last you do the **[PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691853/transform-and-pivot-in-access-2013-sql)** using `category` and values from original `"Dependency_Name"`

Comment: This is what i have so far Juan.SELECT DA.idea_code, DA.dependency_name, COUNT(*) AS row_number
FROM tbl_IdeasDependencies AS DA INNER JOIN tbl_IdeasDependencies AS DA2 ON (DA2.idea_code = DA.idea_code) AND (DA2.dependency_name <= DA.dependency_name)
WHERE DA.Load_Date = (Select Max(Load_Date) from tbl_IdeasDependencies)
GROUP BY DA.idea_code, DA.dependency_name
ORDER BY 1, 3;

Comment: did you made step 1 and 2 in my answer? I cant make the whole code for you because i dont have all the data. I will answer any question you have to make it work.

Comment: Thanks  Juan Carlos Oropeza I was able to fix it.And your solution works great.

Comment: @Birinder Please remember upvote and accept as the correct answer