# GIS SQL Query Logic Syntax

Tags: python, sql, gis

I have a GIS layer that has thousands of Facility IDs.

- For each Facility ID there can be multiple Chemical ID's.
- For each chemical ID there is a maximum of 3 zone types. Zone A, B, C. But there is not always 3 Zone types, it varies.
- And the amount of chemical ID's for each Facility ID can vary from 1 to many.

What I am attempting to do, is Dissolve (or group by) this layer down to display which Facility ID Zone has the largest Buffer Distance while including the ZoneType(important)

Here are the fields

```
             FacilityID, ChemicalID, ZoneType, ZoneDistance
ex rows:        1              2           A          1000
                1              2           B          900
                1              2           C          500
                1              5           A          1200
                1              5           B          900
                1              7           B          2000
                1              7           C          900
                2              13          A          200
                2              13          B          300
                2              13          C          600
```

expected result: 1 row for every FacilityID with the Max Buffer and that specific zone type. So for FacilityID 1- I want one row and it would be ZoneType B with a ZoneDistance of 2000

```
FacilityID,ZoneType, ZoneDistance  
    1          B         2000
    2          C         600
```

I have tried a few SQL statement which I got the Facility ID with the Max ZoneDistance for each ZoneType. I just want the Max ZoneDistance for all the ZoneTypes at a FacilityID.

```
SELECT max(ZoneDistance), ZoneType, FacilityID
FROM AllZones group by ZoneType, FacilityID;
```

I have also tried a Subquery but that did not work either

I am semi new to SQL, and I cannot seem to figure out the logic to get my results. Answers welcomed in SQL or Python

Comment: what gis function are you using? Sql Server,  Postgres, Oracle?

Comment: `Max(ZoneDistance)` Mean buffer area covering all `ZoneType`  from each facility??

Comment: I am using Microsoft Access

Comment: So, is just sql query, GIS isnt relevant here?

Comment: it could be relevant if there is a way to use a GIS tool in either ArcGIS or QGIS

Comment: Also what do you mean by 'GIS Layer'?

Comment: a GIS Layer- think of it as a database table with columns, rows with spatial geometry so it can be displayed in mapping software

Comment: You really should consider using Postgres instead of Access. I work with ArcGis and Qgis and is very good. And make this query would be much easier. Just a `MAX() over (PARTITION BY ZoneType, Facility)`

Comment: Yeah I know Postgres is great but I work for the state and they do not let me download Postgres :( thanks Il give your query a try

Comment: Not, that query doesnt work on Access :(

Comment: What is your expected result from that data?

Comment: 1 row for every FacilityID with the Max Buffer and that specific zone type. So for FacilityID 1- I want one row and it would be ZoneType B with a ZoneDistance of 2000..

Comment: Please update your question and include the exepcted output. The same format you include your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select f.FacilityID, 
     f.ZoneType,
     m.MaxZoneDistance
from AllZones f
     join (
          SELECT max(ZoneDistance) MaxZoneDistance,
               FacilityID 
          FROM AllZones 
          group by FacilityID
          ) m
          on f.facilityID=m.facilityID 
               and MaxZoneDistance=ZoneDistance
```

**OUTPUT**

```
FacilityID  ZoneType    MaxZoneDistance
1           B           2000
2           C           600
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this example in access. I prepare a demo on MySQL.

[Achieving ROW_NUMBER / PARTITION BY in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917637/achieving-row-number-partition-by-in-ms-access)

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/746b653/13)**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT 
            t1.`ZoneType`,
            t1.`FacilityID`,
            t1.`ZoneDistance`,
            COUNT(*) AS `rn`
        FROM       Facility AS t1
        INNER JOIN Facility AS t2
                ON t1.`FacilityID`   = t2.`FacilityID`
               AND t1.`ZoneType`     = t2.`ZoneType`
               AND t1.`ChemicalID`   = t2.`ChemicalID`
               AND t1.`ZoneDistance` <= t2.`ZoneDistance`
        GROUP BY
            t1.`ZoneType`,
            t1.`FacilityID`,
            t1.`ZoneDistance`
        ORDER BY 
            t1.`ZoneType`,
            t1.`FacilityID`,
            t1.`ZoneDistance` DESC
       ) T
WHERE rn = 1      
ORDER BY `ZoneType`,`FacilityID`
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ZoneType | FacilityID | ZoneDistance | rn |
|----------|------------|--------------|----|
|        A |          1 |         1200 |  1 |
|        A |          2 |          200 |  1 |
|        B |          1 |         2000 |  1 |
|        B |          2 |          300 |  1 |
|        C |          1 |          900 |  1 |
|        C |          2 |          600 |  1 |
```

After I saw your result found another method

**[Second DEMO](http://rextester.com/ASII5141)**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT 
            t1.`FacilityID`,
            t1.`ChemicalID`, 
            t1.`ZoneType`, 
            t1.`ZoneDistance`,
             ( SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM Facility as t2
               WHERE t1.`FacilityID` = t2.`FacilityID`
                 AND ( ( t1.`ZoneDistance` < t2.`ZoneDistance`)
                    OR ( t1.`ZoneDistance` = t2.`ZoneDistance` and t1.`ZoneType` > t2.`ZoneType`)
                    OR ( t1.`ZoneDistance` = t2.`ZoneDistance` and t1.`ZoneType` = t2.`ZoneType` and t1.`ChemicalID` > t2.`ChemicalID`)
                     )
             ) as rn
        FROM       Facility AS t1
        ORDER BY 
            t1.`FacilityID`,        
            t1.`ZoneDistance` DESC,
            t1.`ZoneType`, 
            t1.`ChemicalID`
    ) T
WHERE rn = 0;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
FacilityID  ChemicalID  ZoneType    ZoneDistance    rn
2           13          C           600             0
1           7           B           2000            0
```