# access - row_number function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ms-access, analytics

I had this query, which gives me the desired results on `postgres`

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t."Internal_reference", t."Movement_date" ORDER BY t."Movement_date") AS "cnt"
FROM (SELECT
  "Internal_reference",
  MAX("Movement_date") AS maxtime
FROM dw."LO-D4_Movements"
GROUP BY "Internal_reference") r
INNER JOIN dw."LO-D4_Movements" t
  ON t."Movement_date" = r.maxtime
  AND t."Internal_reference" = r."Internal_reference"
```

Issue is I have to translate the query above on `Access` where the analytical function does not exist ...

I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917637/achieving-row-number-partition-by-in-ms-access) to build the query below

```
SELECT 
      t."Internal_reference",
      t.from_code,
      t.to_code,
      t."Movement_date",
      t.shipment_number,
      t."PO_number",
      t."Quantity",
      t."Movement_value",
      t."Site",
      t."Import_date",
  COUNT(*) AS "cnt"
 FROM (
      SELECT "Internal_reference",
      MAX("Movement_date") AS maxtime
      FROM dw."LO-D4_Movements"
      GROUP BY "Internal_reference") r
LEFT OUTER JOIN dw."LO-D4_Movements" t
        ON t."Movement_date" = r.maxtime AND t."Internal_reference" = r."Internal_reference"
GROUP BY
      t.from_code,
      t.to_code,
      t."Movement_date",
      t.shipment_number,
      t."PO_number",
      t."Quantity",
      t."Movement_value",
      t."Site",
      t."Import_date",
      t."Internal_reference" 
ORDER BY t.from_code
```

Issue is I only have `1` in the `cnt` column.

I tried to tweak it by removing the `internal_reference` (see below)

```
SELECT 
      t.from_code,
      t.to_code,
      t."Movement_date",
      t.shipment_number,
      t."PO_number",
      t."Quantity",
      t."Movement_value",
      t."Site",
      t."Import_date",
  COUNT(*) AS "cnt"
 FROM (
      SELECT "Internal_reference",
      MAX("Movement_date") AS maxtime
      FROM dw."LO-D4_Movements"
      GROUP BY "Internal_reference") r
LEFT OUTER JOIN dw."LO-D4_Movements" t
        ON t."Movement_date" = r.maxtime AND t."Internal_reference" = r."Internal_reference"
GROUP BY
      t.from_code,
      t.to_code,
      t."Movement_date",
      t.shipment_number,
      t."PO_number",
      t."Quantity",
      t."Movement_value",
      t."Site",
      t."Import_date" 
ORDER BY t.from_code
```

However, the results are even worse. The `cnt` is growing but it gives me the wrong `cnt`

Any help are more than welcome as I'm slow losing my sanity.

Thanks

---

**Edit:** Please find the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0fa80/2)

Comment: One option is to do a make table query and add an auto number field.

Comment: Hi @TheGambill I'm only extracting data from that table, I'm unsure I want to create a new table and you need vba to create temp table in Access.

Comment: That makes sense... I'm thinking through it. Went to SQL Server long ago... A little rusty on access.

Comment: @TheGambill I'm talking about Access-hit, not sqlserver ;)

Comment: Try changing count to dcount and see if it makes a difference for you.

Comment: @TheGambill dcount is for vba

Comment: Can you create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for your PostgreSQL query that shows some sample data and required results?

Comment: Hi @GordThompson, please find the sqlfiddle in my question. I need to have the same results (see in the fiddle) but with an ANSI sql

Comment: Thanks for posting the fiddle. Access SQL is not ANSI SQL so you'll need to pick one. Also, your VBA comments above suggest that you won't be executing the query from within the Access UI, so how will you be executing it? ... via ODBC? ... OLEDB? ....

Comment: @GordThompson Access SQL will be nice. I'm executing the query through the Access UI but I'm not skilled with VBA. However, if you have a step by step way of doing things, I'm all ear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Gordon-Linoff's code is close to what you want, but there are some typos I couldn't correct without a rewrite, so here's my attempt

```
SELECT
    t1.Internal_reference,
    t1.Movement_date,
    t1.PO_Number as Combination_Of_Columns_Which_Make_This_Unique,
    t1.Other_columns,
    Count(1) AS Cnt
FROM
    ([LO-D4_Movements] AS t1
    INNER JOIN [LO-D4_Movements] AS t2 ON
        t1.Internal_reference = t2.Internal_reference AND
        t1.Movement_date = t2.Movement_date)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            t3.Internal_reference,
            MAX(t3.Movement_date) AS Maxtime
        FROM
            [LO-D4_Movements] AS t3
        GROUP BY
            t3.Internal_reference
            )  AS r ON
        t1.Internal_reference = r.Internal_reference AND
        t1.Movement_date = r.Maxtime
WHERE  
    t1.PO_Number>=t2.PO_Number
GROUP BY
    t1.Internal_reference,
    t1.Movement_date,t1.PO_Number,
    t1.Other_columns
ORDER BY
    t1.Internal_reference,
    t1.Movement_date,
    Count(1);
```

In addition to within the `max(movement_date)` subquery, the main table is brought in twice. One version is the one for showing in your results, the other is for counting records to generate the sequence numbers.

Gordon said you need a unique id column for each row. And that's true if by "column" you mean to include derived columns also. Also it only needs to be unique within any combination of "internal_reference" and "Movement_date".

I've assumed, perhaps wrongly, that PO_Number will suffice. If not, concatenate with that (and some delimeters) other fields which will make it unique. The where clause will need updating to compare t1 and t2 for the "Combination of Columns which make this unique".

If, there is no appropriate combination available, I'm not sure it can be done without VBA and/or temp tables as The-Gambill suggested.

Answer (score -1):

This is a real pain in MS Access, as far as I know.  One method is a correlated subquery, but you need a unique id column on each row:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM (SELECT "Internal_reference", MAX("Movement_date") AS maxtime
              FROM dw."LO-D4_Movements"
              GROUP BY "Internal_reference"
             ) as t2
        WHERE t2."Internal_reference" AND t."Internal_reference" AND

              t2."Movement_date" = t."Movement_date" AND
              t2.?? <= t.??
       ) as cnt
FROM (SELECT "Internal_reference", MAX("Movement_date") AS maxtime
      FROM dw."LO-D4_Movements"
      GROUP BY "Internal_reference"
     ) r INNER JOIN
     dw."LO-D4_Movements" t
     ON t."Movement_date" = r.maxtime AND
        t."Internal_reference" = r."Internal_reference";
```

The `??` is for the id or creation date or something to allow the counting of rows.

Comment: Hi @gordon-linoff, thanks for your query but where the `t2` comes from ...?

Comment: sorry @gordon-linoff your query is not appropriate in this case

Comment: Why would this get an anonymous downvote?  This is how you emulate `row_number()` in MS Access.